# Listing categories alphabetically & total post count

Tags: entries, categories

How do I list all categories in use alphabetically? And how to get the total post count from each category?

Cheers﻿

Answer (score 9):

The [`relatedTo`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) param will do the trick:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.limit(null) %}
{% for category in craft.categories.relatedTo(entries).order('title asc') %}
    {% set entryCount = entries.relatedTo(category).total() %}
    {{ category }} ({{ entryCount }})
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you want to change 'tag' to 'category' in your example. Otherwise your answer should be correct.

Comment: Wow, how'd I forget to change that? Fixed, thanks.