# Listing categories with post count in a nav?

Tags: entries, categories

I'm trying to list my categories (and sub categories, just one sub level) as a nav, and have the number of entries in each of those categories beside each one.

There is another question on here which achieves a simple list [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/394/listing-categories-alphabetically-total-post-count) but trying to apply that logic to what i have for my nav is scrambling my brain as everything I've tried throws an error.

This is what i have, taken from the [Get Help](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category) section of the craft site:

```
<ul>
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('articleCategories') %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Any thoughts on how i can get the number of entries each category has in it, in this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Within your `nav` loop, you would use the method [`count()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#count) with an [`craft.entries` Element Query](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html), to only count the entries that are related to the category you're looping. Pass the category object to the [`relatedTo`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter) parameter.

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('articleCategories') %}

    {# Get the count of entries related to `category` #}
    {% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).count() %}

    {{ entryCount }}

{% endnav %}
```

Comment: Thank you carlcs! You are like a machine :^)
Much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the n+1 query in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

**Bonus Answer.** If you want to sort by the amount of posts each category has you can do the following

```
{% set allCats = craft.categories.group('articleCategories').level(1).find() %}

{% set catArray = {} %}

{% for cat in allCats %}

    {% set catArray = catArray | merge({(cat.slug):craft.entries.relatedTo(cat).total() }) %}

{% endfor %}

{% set catArray = catArray|sort|reverse %}

{% for catSlug, count in catArray %}

    {% set category = craft.categories.slug(catSlug).first() %}

    <li class="categories__item"><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Nice! Could well come in handy :)